# Why is there no `mov %rsp, %rbp` in function prologue?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, stack-memory

In assembly, many functions begin with the following prologue:

```
00000001004010e0: main(int, char**)+0    push    %rbp
00000001004010e1: main(int, char**)+1    mov     %rsp,%rbp
```

Some functions, like the one below, do not:

```
                              int MainEntry(){
                                       MainEntry():
0000000100401104: MainEntry()+0          push    %rbp
0000000100401105: MainEntry()+1          push    %rbx
0000000100401106: MainEntry()+2          sub     $0x48,%rsp
000000010040110a: MainEntry()+6          lea     0x80(%rsp),%rbp
                                        vector<int> v;
0000000100401112: MainEntry()+14         lea     -0x60(%rbp),%rax
0000000100401116: MainEntry()+18         mov     %rax,%rcx
0000000100401119: MainEntry()+21         callq   0x100401b00 <std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::vector()>
                                        return 0;
000000010040111e: MainEntry()+26         mov     $0x0,%ebx
0000000100401123: MainEntry()+31         lea     -0x60(%rbp),%rax
0000000100401127: MainEntry()+35         mov     %rax,%rcx
000000010040112a: MainEntry()+38         callq   0x100401b20 <std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::~vector()>
000000010040112f: MainEntry()+43         mov     %ebx,%eax
                                     }
```

Here is the C++ code that compiles into this:

```
int main(int c, char** args){
    MainEntry();
    return 0;
}

int MainEntry(){
    vector<int> v;
    return 0;
}
```

So here are my two questions:

1. In the *MainEntry* function, there is a `push %rbp`, and then a `push %rbx`. Why is RBX pushed onto the stack?
2. If I understand correctly, `sub $0x48, %rsp` allocates 0x48 bytes on the stack, and `lea 0x80(%rsp), %rbp` moves 0x80 bytes *down* on the stack and assigns that as the base. Where is RBP going to end up in the local stack frame and how did it get there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `rbx` is pushed onto the stack because the calling convention says it is preserved across calls.
2. This function is compiled without frame pointers. `rbp` is just another general purpose register when compiling without frame pointers.

About the question in the title (now improved)
The `push rsp, rbp` instruction doesn't exist. `push` always takes **one** argument. Perhaps you meant to ask why  `rbp` isn't pushed. The answer is that nothing uses it and so no instructions are required to preserve it.

Comment: yeah i meant to say `mov rsp, rbp` in title. `rbp` is being pushed, but the way it's assigned is strange. it allocates `0x48` bytes for vector i presume, and then moves `0x80` bytes down the stack to set `rbp`

Comment: `MainEntry` does use frame pointers.  The `lea 0x80(%rsp),%rbp` sets up the frame (by adding 0x80 bytes to the stack pointer and storing it in `rbp`), and the addressing for local variables is relative to `rbp`.  If frame pointers were not used, the local variables would be addressed relative to `rsp`.

Comment: i just checked registers and it appears like MainEntry()'s `rbp` is the same value as main()'s `rbp`. So both `main` and `MainEntry` use the same base pointer. thats why there's such a large offset of `0x80 bytes`.